# multiple activities in nativescript

Tags: android, android-activity, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I want to have many android activities in a nativescript app, but don't know how.

I've used the method in https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/android-runtime/advanced-topics/extend-application-activity

and add all the activities to webpack config.

but now both of the newly created activity-a and activity-b called the default angular app.component, so the constructor and ngOnInit are called multiple times.

how to make these activities map to different components, or just to be a simple android activity without calling the default app.component.

Comment: As per the docs, In order to build the app with webpack, the absolute path to the file where the Android activity is extended should be added to the appComponents array.

Comment: May I ask why you need multiple activities? NativeScript is designed to work on single activity and uses fragments for navigation within the Activity. You can have multiple activities for various purpose but there should be only one main activity that extends NativeScriptActivity.

Comment: @Manoj
My current app will take a very long time to load, so I want to have a splash screen. 
To have a splash screen, I use a similar method that this post https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/animating-splash-screen-using-nativescript/3944/4 uses.
I created _activity-b_ just for the splash screen.
My _activity-a_ has transparent background and is a small modal dialog on top of other apps. The transparent background will make the general splashscreen that nativescript uses disappear, that's why I created this strange _activity-b_.

Comment: As you see in the example itself, the first activity is not an extension of NativeScript Activity, you will see your component loading twice only if you use 2 NativeScript Activity loaded one after another.

Comment: @Narendra
The activities are ok to run, but I want the _activity-b_ not to run the app.component code, I hope it to do nothing. And I may create _activity-c_ in the future, and it should use a different component.

Comment: @Manoj
Thx, I changed the code from nativescript js file back to android java file, and it's ok for that part now.